# Memory leak when pushing a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

Each time I push a new viewcontroller, it adds about 3MB.  TestVC is a brand new VC with one method for pushing a new version of the VC.

```
 UIViewController *vc = [[TestVC alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil]; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    [vc release];
```

When I popviewController, it doesn't release any memory (watching activity monitor).

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

So, as I add navigate through the app (about 60 different pages), memory keeps building up.  Does initWithNibName need something special.  When I pop, do I need to release the nib somehow?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're doing there. Are you sure the problem is not attributed to something else?

Comment: What does `TestVC` look like? Do you release all your properties? No other memory leaks in there? As David says, there's nothing wrong with the way you're adding/removing view controllers.

Comment: TestVC is an empty VC, except for the one IBAction to call the pushViewController code. The XIB file is has one button in it and a background image.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely problem is a failure to `release` something in `-[TestVC dealloc]`. I would evaluate that method by inspection first. If you can't find the problem, use the Leaks instrument in Instruments to find what particular thing is being over-retained. If Leaks doesn't find it, then use the heapshot tool in Instruments to see what's being allocated. With something so large, it should be easy to find. There's a quick overview of using Heapshot on [Use Your Loaf](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/3/8/using-heapshots-to-find-abandoned-memory.html).

Comment: Using heapshots would be the first thing I'd do when diagnosing this.  See also Bill Bumgarner's writeup on this here: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/